# How to display characters in Terminal

Tags: java, linux, terminal

I am coding a blackjack game in Java and am using unicode characters for the suits. On a windows computer, I needed to change the font in the command prompt in order to see the symbols, but I do not know what I need to do with Terminal to solve the problem. I am currently running Linux Mint. I tried looking for an answer, but could not find one.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "ASCII symbols for the suits"? There are no characters in ASCII that represent card suits. There are characters that are shown in some character encodings (for characters 2, 3, 4 and 5, if I remember rightly) but that's not ASCII. The *Unicode* card symbols are U+2660-U+2667 - see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Playing_cards_in_Unicode

Comment: Please be more specific: which ASCII symbols? What, if anything, _does_ appear? What font? I suspect you're barking up the wrong tree -- use Unicode symbols common to all fonts, not ASCII symbols from a special font (e.g. Wingdings). If there's any relevant source code to share, share it.

Comment: @Jon @JakeRobb sorry, I wasn't sure how to phrase my question. ```(char)4``` That's how I'm trying to display the characters

Comment: Right, well that's the [Unicode end of transmission](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0004/index.htm) character. So I'd start off by not doing that - use the Unicode characters referenced earlier.

Comment: @Jon Will that display in Command Prompt also because I need to make sure that my teacher can see the suits when I hand in my game?

Comment: You should test it. You may need to ask your teacher to set the code page to use UTF-8 (but you shouldn't need to change font)

Comment: @Jon Thank you, it works for me now. I'll just let my teacher know.